# Change version of a dependent gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am installing through Bundler a gem A that depends on a version of another gem `faraday-stack 0.1.3` that is lower than what is required (`requires faraday-stack 0.1.5`) by still another gem B. How can I force the first gem A's dependency to the higher one `0.1.5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If gem A is specifying an exact version of 0.1.3, that indicates that it is incompatible with later versions such as 0.1.5.

It could be that the dependency for gem A is incorrectly over-constrained, and in reality it would work with 0.1.5 if the gemspec allowed it. If that's the case, the gemspec for gem A needs to be fixed to have a more permissive dependency on faraday-stack (for example, `~> 0.1.5`, which means the same as `>= 0.1.5, < 0.2.0`).

On the other hand, if gem A actually is incompatible with faraday-stack 0.1.5, then what you're trying to do won't work. Either gem A will need to be updated so that it works with 0.1.5, or gem B will need to be updated so that it works with 0.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the version of the faraday-stack gem in your Gemfile before gem A or B.

```
gem 'faraday-stack', '0.1.5'
gem 'A'
gem 'B'
```

I believe this is pretty much a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434263/can-i-force-a-gems-dependencies-in-gemfile) question.